# How can I produce this sparsity pattern elegantly with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For a D-dimensional problem I'm trying to generate a 2d `ndarray` with a particular sparsity pattern.

I've been trying to figure out how to interleave vectors using `np.meshgrid` and the like but just can't get there.

The sparsity matrix (it doesn't need to actually be sparse, just contain `0`s and `1`s) is of shape `(2^D, D)` where D is the number of dimensions.

For D=2 the matrix looks like this:

```
two_d = [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 1],
]
```

For D=3 it's like this:

```
three_d = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
]
```

It's a super obvious sparsity pattern but I'm struggling figure out how to reproduce that elegantly with numpy.

*Note: the row-ordering doesn't actually matter, as long as all rows are present.*

Comment: `np.indices((2,2)).T.reshape(-1,2)` and `np.indices((2,2,2)).T.reshape(-1,3)`, last parameter is `len(shape)` or *D* in your case.

Comment: Beautiful, @MichaelSzczesny thank you so much. Chuck it in a short answer and I'll give you the credit!

Comment: I'd rather wait for a more elegant solution. Transpose and reshape still seems cumbersome to me.

Comment: I'll grant that the code isn't obvious, but it's elegant in every other respect so you have my eternal thanks :)

Comment: @Michael, `indices` is doing the hard work.  The rest is just cosmetic.  It doesn't add any new values.

Comment: @hpaulj - I know, but it's hard to predict the exact output for more complicated shapes. There is [`np.ndindex`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html) but it's an iterator(!). I don't know how to get iterators work well with `numpy`.

Comment: Having illustrated several options, I realized I should have first insisted on seeing **your**  efforts at using `meshgrid`.  **elegance** in `numpy` is a luxury that should be "paid for" with effort!

Comment: @hpaulj Never fear, I'd been trying for about four hours before posting on here: as a PhD in fluid dynamics *should* be able to do this... no shortage of effort, although it appears my once-sharp talent is waning :( - Mostly variations on `meshgrid([[0,1] for _ in range(D)])` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eligigance is in the eye of the beholder.  There are a number of tools for generating the values; putting them into the desired layout is just basic `numpy` manipulation.

A good basic way to produce these arrays is:

```
In [6]: np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat=2)))
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
In [7]: np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat=3)))
Out[7]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

From the comments:

```
In [16]: np.indices((2,2))
Out[16]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
In [17]: np.indices((2,)*2).T.reshape(-1,2)
Out[17]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1]])
In [18]: np.indices((2,)*3).T.reshape(-1,3)
Out[18]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       ...

In [20]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(2),np.arange(2),indexing='ij')
Out[20]: 
[array([[0, 0],
        [1, 1]]),
 array([[0, 1],
        [0, 1]])]
In [21]: np.transpose(np.meshgrid(np.arange(2),np.arange(2),indexing='ij')).resh
    ...: ape(-1,2)
Out[21]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

The 'ij' isn't essential; it just makes an initial set of arrays that looks like the `indices`.

`mgrid` also can be used.  and:

```
np.array(list(np.ndindex(2,2,2)))
```

Another approach is to reverse engineer `three_d`.

```
In [55]: res = np.zeros((2**3,3),int)
```

Setting every other element of the 1st column is easy:

```
In [56]: res[1::2,0]=1
In [57]: res
Out[57]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

setting pairs of values in the 2nd is trickier:

```
In [58]: res[:,1].reshape(-1,4)[:,2:]=1
In [59]: res
Out[59]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

setting a contiguous block of the third is again easy:

```
In [60]: res[4:,2]=1
In [61]: res
Out[61]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: I really like the `((2,)*x).reshape(-1,x)` improvement.

Comment: Thank you very much @hpaulj - incredibly thorough!